# CloudFront + WhiteNoise : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ;

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Django with WhiteNoise.
On the index page at dailyhn.com, it's ok.
But when I access child pages on the left panel, errors happens like this.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ; http://www.dailyhn.com/news/2016/01/08/d3urtm1uacryxt.cloudfront.net/static/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.2f624089c65f.css

Any body have this problem before. I've searched the whole web, along with Amazon CloudFront + Django WhiteNoise documentation, but can not find out appropriate solution.

Comment: How are you including the links to the static content in your template?

Comment: I've already. Before apply whitenoise, it's running ok.

Comment: {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

    {% block head_title %}dailyhn.com{% endblock %}
    {% block extra_head %}
        <link href="{% static 'news/css/dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'news/css/news.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="{% static 'js/holder.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

Comment: Please show your static settings.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
] STATIC_ROOT = "../static/" # WhiteNoise
STATIC_HOST = get_secret("DJANGO_STATIC_HOST")
STATIC_URL = STATIC_HOST + '/static/'
WHITENOISE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../static")

Comment: This is my settings for static. I try to find out solutions for this several days. I wonder whether I should configure something at CloudFront console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained the issue with the STATIC_HOST setting here: https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/issues/61#issuecomment-170504687

There are instructions for how to configure CloudFront here:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/django.html#instructions-for-amazon-cloudfront

Comment: Thanks Evans. I miss the leading forward slashes and didn't notice that. Change from DJANGO_STATIC_HOST = "d3urtm1uacryxt.cloudfront.net"  to  DJANGO_STATIC_HOST = "//d3urtm1uacryxt.cloudfront.net" then it works.